# How to perform SOQL query after retrieving access_token and instance_url via oAuth2 flow?

Tags: soql, query, oauth2, c#

I have successfully setup my oAuth2 flow, created a Connected App and I can retrieve an access_token and instance_url just fine. Now that I have those two pieces of data, how can I perform SOQL queries in C#?

Currently my code is:

```
        var client = new SforceService();
        client.Url = instanceUrl;
        client.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
        client.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = accessToken;
        client.query($"SELECT Id FROM Attachment");
```

However when the client.query() function gets hit, Salesforce returns the login page instead of the expected rows, even though I already granted access to my Connected App for that user and successfully retrieved the access_token

Is there another way I should be performing the query? Is there another piece of data I need to provide the SforceService() object?

Comment: Can you print to see if accessToken you are getting is valid or not?
And what permissions you have given to connected app? does your user have API access?

Comment: It is a valid token. The problem was (and I will answer my question in a sec) that the instance URL was not the web service URL. My SforceService() needs the web service URL. The two URLs are similar, but not the same

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed the web service URL and not the instance URL. To get the web service URL I need to perform a GET on the identity URL with the access_token used as a query param. This identity URL is in the same JSON blob that the access_token is, under property "id". This GET will return a JSON blob containing lot of info on the user, including which URLs they have access to. In my case I needed the 'partner' URL contained in that blob and passed that into my client.Url property. See https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yzmIAA for more info